# LineageOS 18 -> USB storage is not being attached

Tags: usb, storage, lineageos, adoptable-storage, usb-mass-storage

I am using Raspberry Pi with installed [LineageOS 18](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS18/) and basically all works well. The only issue I do have is that when I put an USB stick (storage) it is not visible in the GUI. I tried several USB dongles and SD-Card reader. No luck.
I can see it's being recognised correctly:

```
01-01 18:10:24.804     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using dwc2
01-01 18:10:25.010     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5583, bcdDevice= 1.00
01-01 18:10:25.019     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
01-01 18:10:25.027     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.3: Product:  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
01-01 18:10:25.032     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.3: Manufacturer:  USB
01-01 18:10:25.036     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.3: SerialNumber: 0101a3136a5ad2527acb7f7f1499daffd9e96a0672c0c4bf5b3297da4b20ff1acb9900000000000000000000943a3a96ff8b520083558107b9aa4123
01-07 09:16:29.008   247   247 I drm-event-liste: type=1400 audit(0.0:857): avc: denied { read } for path="socket:[14421]" dev="sockfs" ino=14421 scontext=u:r:hal_graphics_composer_default:s0 tcontext=u:r:hal_graphics_composer_default:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1
01-01 18:10:25.054     0     0 I usb-storage 1-1.2.3: 1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
01-01 18:10:25.086     0     0 I scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2.3:1.0
01-07 09:16:29.050   401   556 D UsbHostManager: USB device attached: vidpid 0781:5583 mfg/product/ver/serial  USB/ SanDisk 3.2Gen1/1.00/0101a3136a5ad2527acb7f7f1499daffd9e96a0672c0c4bf5b3297da4b20ff1acb9900000000000000000000943a3a96ff8b520083558107b9aa4123 hasAudio/HID/Storage: false/false/true
01-07 09:16:29.052   401   556 D UsbDeviceDescriptor:   1 configs
01-07 09:16:29.052   401   556 D UsbHostManager: Added device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/011,mVendorId=1921,mProductId=21891,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName= USB,mProductName= SanDisk 3.2Gen1,mVersion=1.00,mSerialNumberReader=com.android.server.usb.UsbSerialReader@1fdb59c, mHasAudioPlayback=false, mHasAudioCapture=false, mHasMidi=false, mHasVideoCapture=false, mHasVideoPlayback=false, mConfigurations=[
01-07 09:16:29.052   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=128,mMaxPower=112,mInterfaces=[
01-07 09:16:29.052   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=8,mSubclass=6,mProtocol=80,mEndpoints=[
01-07 09:16:29.052   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=0]
01-07 09:16:29.052   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbEndpoint[mAddress=2,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=0]]]]
01-07 09:16:29.086  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver: New USB mass-storage device attached.
01-07 09:16:29.086  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   name:  USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1
01-07 09:16:29.088  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   serialNumber: 0101a3136a5ad2527acb7f7f1499daffd9e96a0672c0c4bf5b3297da4b20ff1acb9900000000000000000000943a3a96ff8b520083558107b9aa4123
01-07 09:16:29.088  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   productId: 21891
01-07 09:16:29.088  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   vendorId: 1921
01-07 09:16:29.088  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   isMassStorage: true
01-07 09:16:29.088  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver: Checking if this is the current backup drive.
01-07 09:16:29.337   401   422 W LocationManagerService: blocking 0,0 location from gps provider
01-01 18:10:26.110     0     0 I scsi 0  : 0:0:0: Direct-Access      USB      SanDisk 3.2Gen1 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
01-01 18:10:26.125     0     0 I sd 0    : 0:0:0: [sda] 240353280 512-byte logical blocks: (123 GB/115 GiB)
01-01 18:10:26.134     0     0 I sd 0    : 0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
01-01 18:10:26.139     0     0 D sd 0    : 0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
01-01 18:10:26.140     0     0 I sd 0    : 0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
01-07 09:16:30.132    28    28 I kdevtmpfs: type=1400 audit(0.0:858): avc: denied { create } for name="sda" scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
01-01 18:10:26.223     0     0 I sda     : sda1
01-01 18:10:26.229     0     0 I ueventd : vendor_create_device_symlinks: device sda
01-01 18:10:26.236     0     0 I sd 0    : 0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
01-01 18:10:26.239     0     0 I ueventd : vendor_create_device_symlinks: device sda1
01-01 18:10:26.249     0     0 E ueventd : Failed to symlink /dev/block/sda1 to /dev/block/by-name/boot, which already links to: /dev/block/mmcblk0p1: File exists
```

The only error here seems to be the `Failed to symlink /dev/block/sda1` message. However when I add another one all seems to be working fine:

```
01-01 18:13:24.148     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using dwc2
01-01 18:13:24.354     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5571, bcdDevice= 1.00
01-01 18:13:24.362     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
01-01 18:13:24.370     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.4: Product: Cruzer Fit
01-01 18:13:24.376     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.4: Manufacturer: SanDisk
01-01 18:13:24.380     0     0 I usb 1-1.2.4: SerialNumber: 4C530010541126100030
01-01 18:13:24.388     0     0 I usb-storage 1-1.2.4: 1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
01-01 18:13:24.395     0     0 I scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2.4:1.0
01-07 09:19:28.359   401   556 D UsbHostManager: USB device attached: vidpid 0781:5571 mfg/product/ver/serial SanDisk/Cruzer Fit/1.00/4C530010541126100030 hasAudio/HID/Storage: false/false/true
01-07 09:19:28.361   401   556 D UsbDeviceDescriptor:   1 configs
01-07 09:19:28.362   401   556 D UsbHostManager: Added device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/013,mVendorId=1921,mProductId=21873,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName=SanDisk,mProductName=Cruzer Fit,mVersion=1.00,mSerialNumberReader=com.android.server.usb.UsbSerialReader@ec44085, mHasAudioPlayback=false, mHasAudioCapture=false, mHasMidi=false, mHasVideoCapture=false, mHasVideoPlayback=false, mConfigurations=[
01-07 09:19:28.362   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=128,mMaxPower=112,mInterfaces=[
01-07 09:19:28.362   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=8,mSubclass=6,mProtocol=80,mEndpoints=[
01-07 09:19:28.362   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=0]
01-07 09:19:28.362   401   556 D UsbHostManager: UsbEndpoint[mAddress=2,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=512,mInterval=0]]]]
01-07 09:19:28.368  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver: New USB mass-storage device attached.
01-07 09:19:28.368  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   name: SanDisk Cruzer Fit
01-07 09:19:28.369  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   serialNumber: 4C530010541126100030
01-07 09:19:28.369  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   productId: 21873
01-07 09:19:28.369  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   vendorId: 1921
01-07 09:19:28.369  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver:   isMassStorage: true
01-07 09:19:28.370  6446  6446 D UsbIntentReceiver: Checking if this is the current backup drive.
01-01 18:13:25.406     0     0 I scsi 1  : 0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Fit       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
01-07 09:19:29.379   401   422 W LocationManagerService: blocking 0,0 location from gps provider
01-01 18:13:25.417     0     0 I sd 1    : 0:0:0: [sdb] 124059648 512-byte logical blocks: (63.5 GB/59.2 GiB)
01-01 18:13:25.427     0     0 I sd 1    : 0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
01-01 18:13:25.432     0     0 D sd 1    : 0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
01-01 18:13:25.433     0     0 I sd 1    : 0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
01-01 18:13:25.473     0     0 I sdb     : sdb1
01-01 18:13:25.479     0     0 I ueventd : vendor_create_device_symlinks: device sdb
01-01 18:13:25.480     0     0 I sd 1    : 0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
01-01 18:13:25.490     0     0 I ueventd : vendor_create_device_symlinks: device sdb1
```

So I am not entirely sure if this is an issue.

I can also see all partitions:

```
cat /proc/partitions                                                                                                                                                                                              
major minor  #blocks  name

   1        0       8192 ram0
   1        1       8192 ram1
   1        2       8192 ram2
   1        3       8192 ram3
   1        4       8192 ram4
   1        5       8192 ram5
   1        6       8192 ram6
   1        7       8192 ram7
   1        8       8192 ram8
   1        9       8192 ram9
   1       10       8192 ram10
   1       11       8192 ram11
   1       12       8192 ram12
   1       13       8192 ram13
   1       14       8192 ram14
   1       15       8192 ram15
 179        0   30535680 mmcblk0
 179        1     131072 mmcblk0p1
 179        2    2097152 mmcblk0p2
 179        3     262144 mmcblk0p3
 179        4   28044288 mmcblk0p4
   8        0  120176640 sda
   8        1  120176624 sda1
   8       16   62029824 sdb
   8       17   62028800 sdb1
```

And I can mount these manually. But I'd expect it will be automatically mounted and visible in user space.

I also know that it works for many people using Raspberry Pi and LineageOS. I also don't have any other issues with USB. I have keyboard, touchscreen, webcam and other things and all works fine. **Only storage not**.

The only difference is that I am using Compute Module 4 instead of regular Raspberry Pi 4. But I cannot imagine it's a hardware issue.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Alternatively: Is there a way to mount a storage that way that I can access it from GUI? As far I understand the user space is rather emulated. I tried to mount it to /sdcard/Storage but it doesn't work like that. I assume it has to be attached to the not emulated file system.

**EDIT**: Additional infos as requested by Irfan. Thanks for the hint:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/sda1/uevent                                                                                                                                                                                  
MAJOR=8
MINOR=1
DEVNAME=sda1
DEVTYPE=partition
PARTN=1

cat /sys/block/sdb/sdb1/uevent                                                                                                                                                                                  
MAJOR=8
MINOR=17
DEVNAME=sdb1
DEVTYPE=partition
PARTN=1
```

Comment: "*Failed to symlink `/dev/block/sda1` to `/dev/block/by-name/boot`, which already links to: `/dev/block/mmcblk0p1`: File exists*". So do not use `boot` as the partition or filesystem label on your USB drive to avoid the name contradiction. Use [`gdisk`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/gdisk.html) or [`parted`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/parted.8.html) to change the partition name and remove the `boot` flag if set. Or simply recreate the MBR partition table using e.g. [`fdisk`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fdisk.8.html).

Comment: yeah that's a bit weird because I don't have boot (called) partition on that storage so I don't really understand the error message

Comment: What does `grep PARTNAME /sys/block/sda/sda1/uevent` show?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Irfan. Added to the main post

Comment: As per [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r1/init/devices.cpp#432) the error should occur only if the `boot` partition name or `boot` flag is set on the first partition on your USB drive. So you need to troubleshoot the problem accordingly. Or jump directly to the solution I suggested earlier i.e. recreate the partition (NOT filesystem). You may want to start by looking at the partition table first.